# White/TestStack UI Automation - clicks app button opens a browser, how do I check the url?

Tags: windows, automation, browser-automation, white-framework

I am currently using White/TestStack to test a windows app.

There are scenarios that requires user to click on links to open pages on browser.  How do I check the hyperlink is working?

Comment: Is the hyperlink opening in a embedded browser or a external browser?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but in case somebody else looking for an answer:

If you check in the [White](https://github.com/TestStack/White/tree/master/src) GitHub repository and you browse the UITests and the control tests, you will find the [Hyperlink control test](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/6c61106f2a62686636eb7cace0ee187a02db7295/src/TestStack.White.UITests/ControlTests/HyperlinkTests.cs). In the sourcecode, you will find several tests according the type of framework used.

The simplest one:

```
var hyperlink = MainWindow.Get<Hyperlink>("LinkLabel");
hyperlink.Click(10, 10);
Assert.That(hyperlink.HelpText, Is.EqualTo("Hyperlink Clicked"));
```

The test is based on the used of code-behind for the [MainWindow](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/6c61106f2a62686636eb7cace0ee187a02db7295/src/TestApplications/WpfTestApplication/MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```
private void Hyperlink_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AutomationProperties.SetHelpText(LinkLabel, "Hyperlink Clicked");
}
```

XAML code of the hyperlink in the MainWindow

```
<TextBlock x:Name="LinkLabelContainer">
    <Hyperlink x:Name="LinkLabel" Click="Hyperlink_OnClick">Link Text</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

So you can used the same method.

---

**TL;DR**

You can link the `Click()` event of your hyperlinks to a method in code behind which update the automation property **HelpText** of the hyperlink with a specific value for the clicked event.

So in your tests, you will just have to perform the click and then check the automation property value.